# Disable multitap on touchpad

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics, multi-touch

I need to disable multitap on the Synaptics touchpad on my Kubuntu 22.04 notebook because I frequently paste the clipboard by accident. I still need any number of fingers (at least one finger) to be a left click.

So far I found $HOME/.config/touchpadxlibinputrc and set both lrmTapButtonMap=false and lmrTapButtonMap=false to no effect. I haven't found any documentation for that file and don't know if it is even used.

Most of the rest of what I found was too old and referred to packages that are no longer easily available.

I did find this [article](https://smarttech101.com/libinput-fix-your-linux-touchpad-using-libinput/), but it doesn't do exactly what I want and my /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ directory is empty and I don't want to start adding things I don't understand.

--- edit ---

I was able to swap the actions associated with two- and three-finger multi-touches, so now a two finger touch emulates a mouse right click and a three finger touch paste the clipboard. This isn't a solution, but the context menu that appears from the emulated right click doesn't alter any text I'm working on and is easier to dismiss. Accidental three finger multi-touches don't occur frequently, so overall, this is an improvement.